# Select Multiple Buttons using angular

Tags: angular, button, colors, background, angular9

```html
<div *ngFor="let value of values">`
 <button>{{value}}</button>`
</div>
```

On click I need to change the background color of the selected buttons.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this just another way but create a directive is the appropriate way as in **Alexander** answer

```html
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
    <button #btn (click)="btn.classList.add('selected')">{{value}}</button>
</div>
```

in case you want to toggle a class use `toggle` instead of `add`

```html
    <button #btn (click)="btn.classList.add('selected')">{{value}}</button>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqlpta?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Can we toggle back to normal on double click.?

Comment: yes it possible but in that case it better to follow Alexander answer by creating directive

Comment: check my updated answer you may use toggle instead of add this will toggle the class

Answer (score 1):

- create a directive with a HostListener for the click event
- inject ElementRef & Renderer2
- in the host listener method, call renderer2.addClass(this.elemenentRef, 'class-with-color-for-button')

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-button-toggle-group multiple="true" appearance="legacy" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Use

```
multiple="true"
```

for multi select Option

Demo URL : [Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nneqopqxmrv?file=app%2Fbutton-toggle-appearance-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to print the days and add toggle functionality your html should be

```
<div *ngFor="let day of weekDays; let i = index" style="display: inline-block;">
                                <button mat-mini-fab [color]="day.status ? 'primary' : ''" 
                                 (click)="ChangeWeekDayStatus(i)">
                                 {{day.text}}</button> &nbsp;</div>
                                                             </div>
```

and your .ts should contain an array

```
 weekDays: Week_Day[] = [
      {
        text: "MO",
        status: false
      }, {
        text: "TU",
        status: true
      }, {
        text: "WE",
        status: false
      }, {
        text: "TH",
        status: false
      }, {
        text: "FR",
        status: false
      }, {
        text: "SA",
        status: false
      }, {
        text: "SU",
        status: false
      }
    ];
```

and a function to handle toggle

```
 ChangeWeekDayStatus(index:number){
    this.weekDays[index].status=!this.weekDays[index].status;
  }
```